# PHP, combine two arrays into a new array, using the first array's values as the keys

Tags: php, arrays, list, key

I have two arrays I want to combine. I need to take the values from the first array, use these values as the keys to match from the second array, and combine them into a third array (the one I'll use).

In other words, I have this first array:

```
Array
(
[24] => 5
[26] => 4
[27] => 2
)
```

The second array I have:

```
Array
(
[1] => McDonalds
[2] => Burger King
[3] => Wendys
[4] => Taco Bell
[5] => Hardees
)
```

And finally, this is the array I want to have:

```
Array
(
[5] => Hardees
[4] => Taco Bell
[2] => Burger King
)
```

Seems easy enough, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried various array functions, such as array_intersect_key, with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) solution:

```
$combined = array();

foreach ($array1 as $v) {
    if (isset($array2[$v])) {
        $combined[$v] = $array2[$v];
    }
}
```

And a [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) solution:

```
// Note that elements of $combined will retain the order of $array2, not $array1
$combined = array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($array1));
```

Comment: +1, his question title confused me about array_combine. Good call.

Comment: @jasonbar: Got me too for a while.

Comment: And special thanks for including two types of solutions. This is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach (array_flip($keys) as $k) {
    $result[$k] = $values[$k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In just one line:

```
foreach ($a as $v) $c[$v]=$b[$v];
```

See:

```
$a=array(24=>5,26=>4,27=>2);
$b=array(1=>'McDonalds',2=>'Burger King',3=>'Wendys',4=>'Taco Bell',5=>'Hardees');

foreach ($a as $v) $c[$v]=$b[$v];

print_r($c);
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Hardees
    [4] => Taco Bell
    [2] => Burger King
)
```

Answer (score -1):

[array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) does what you want natively

The first argument is the array of your fast food restaurants, the second argument is the first array you gave (the keys you want)

e.g:

```
$array = array_keys(array(0 => 'McDonalds', 1 => 'BurgerKing', 2 => 'Taco Bell'),
  array(0 => 1));
$array will only have BurgerKing in it
```

Comment: $array = array_keys($theKeys, $fastFood);

// This returned a blank array. Is this format incorrect?